# How to get javascript date format using C# code behind

Tags: c#, javascript, kendo-ui

I am using Kendo calender and need to highlight specific dates in the calender. As per the kendo demo the dates to be highlighted is wriiten in javascript as follows:

```
 dueDates= [
                           +new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), 8),
                           +new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), 12),
                           +new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), 24),
                           +new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth() + 1, 6),
                           +new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth() + 1, 7),
                           +new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth() + 1, 25),
                           +new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth() + 1, 27),
                           +new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth() - 1, 3),
                           +new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth() - 1, 5),
                           +new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth() - 2, 22),
                           +new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth() - 2, 27)
                        ];
```

and the value of dueDates is :

```
[1357583400000,1357929000000,1358965800000,1360089000000,1360175400000,
1361730600000,1361903400000,1354473000000,1354645800000,1353522600000,1353954600000]
```

I have the date list in code behind and need to convert to the date in the above mentioned format. Kindly help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This number `1357583400000` looks like the `TotalMilliSeconds` from `01-01-1970` ([Unix Epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)). To Convert it back to .Net DateTime. You can do:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).AddMilliseconds(1357583400000);
```

And the you will get: `{07/01/2013 6:30:00 PM}` as DateTime

Comment: Thanks for replying. But I need the data as '1357583400000'   instead of date. Tried giving 'new DateTime(2013, 1, 8).ToFileTimeUtc();' and the value is '130020768000000000' which again does not work.

Comment: @psobhan, You can use TimeSpan.  `(dt - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalMilliseconds` will give you the total milliseconds, which would be: `1357583400000`

Comment: Thanks.Added -5.5 hours to highlight the specific dates in the calender.DateTime due = Convert.ToDateTime(date).AddHours(-5.5);